# rich:calendar and "The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property ..." error

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I have the following situation:

**Interface**

```
public interface Ranged{
public Object getRangeStart();
public Object getRangeEnd();

public void setRangeStart(Object rangeStart);
public void setRangeEnd(Object rangeEnd);

public void setRange(boolean isRange);
public boolean getRange();}
```

implementing class:

```
public class CreationDateRange implements Ranged, Serializable{
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = SerialVersionUID.getSerialVersionUID();

public DateRange()
{
    super();
}

private Date    dateFrom;
private Date    dateTo;
private boolean isRange = false;

public Object getRangeStart()
{
    return (Date)dateFrom;
}

public Object getRangeEnd()
{
    return (Date)dateTo;
}

public void setRangeStart( Object from )
{
    this.dateFrom = (Date)from;
}

public void setRangeEnd( Object to )
{
    this.dateTo = (Date)to;
}

public void setRange( boolean isRange )
{
    this.isRange = isRange;
}

public boolean getRange()
{
    return isRange;
}}
```

**Model:**

```
private Object  updateDate  = new DateRange();

private Object  creationDate    = new DateRange();

public void setUpdateDate( Object updateDate )
{
    this.updateDate = updateDate;
}

public Object getUpdateDate()
{
    return updateDate;
}

public void setCreationDate( Object creationDate )
{
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public Object getCreationDate()
{
    return creationDate;
}
```

**jsf:**

```
<f:viewParam name="creationDate" value="#{doiListController.model.creationDate}"/>
<f:viewParam name="updateDate" value="#{doiListController.model.updateDate}"/>
...
<td style="font-size: 5pt; border: 0; min-width:60px">
  <rich:calendar value="#{listModel.creationDate.rangeStart}"
        datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" enableManualInput="true"
        rendered="#{listModel.creationDate.range}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-mm-dd" />
  </rich:calendar>
</td>
```

**Error:**

```
>[exec] javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /view/doi/doiListView.xhtml @90,59 value="#{listModel.creationDate.rangeStart}": The cla
ss 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'rangeStart'.
     [exec]     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:853)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:735)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1231)
     [exec]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
     [exec]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
     [exec]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
     [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
     [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
     [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
     [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
     [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
     [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
     [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
     [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
     [exec]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
     [exec]     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
     [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
     [exec] Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /view/doi/doiListView.xhtml @90,59 value="#{listModel.creationDate.rangeStart}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not ha
ve the property 'rangeStart'.
     [exec]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:133)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:818)
     [exec]     ... 34 more
```

Can someone help me and say me what am I missing, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception and stacktrace is telling that `#{listModel.creationDate}` is *actually* a `String` during the update model values phase of the form submit request.

That can for example happen if something in your view has called `listMode.setCreationDate()` with a `String` as argument beforehand. For example, by a `<f:viewParam>`, `<h:inputHidden>`, `Converter`-for-class, or whatever else is returning a `String` instead of the desired object type.

Put a breakpoint on the setter method and track the root cause down in the stack. Alternatively, you can also replace `Object` type by `Ranged` type or somehing more specific, so that JSF would possibly throw/display a conversion exception/error which is usually more self-explaining.

Comment: I replaced Object with Ranged and now I get the following error: "Conversion Error setting value 'ch.ethz.id.wai.doi.DateRange@8e36c0' for 'null Converter'". Anyway, I set Object as type because the date can be a range or a normal" specific date. Leaving Object as type, I can use the same field for the two cases and discriminating later in the business logic... Tell me if it will be more helpful if I add all the code and not only pieces...

Comment: I updated the code above with the suggestions from Doug and added a couple of relating f:viewParam. Maybe will help... (I went back to Object, as it is what I would like to have for the above reasons)

Comment: OK, you have definitely incorrectly somewhere a `#{listModel.creationDate}` reference in the view which is setting a `String`. Remove it, you seem to not need it at all. Please read the 2nd paragraph and/or put a breakpoint in the setter method.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread: http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-25143.html

Which suggests that JSF may be using your setters (which accept `Object`) to set the value as a String.

Why do you hate type saftey?

You should make your fields typed - `UpdateDateRange`, `CreationDateRange` or at least just `Ranged` (why do you have two classes to implement `Ranged`? Aren't these just two instances of the same type in two different fields?)

Comment: JSF/EL does not call setters on nested properties without reason. It only calls it for the "endpoint" of the EL expression. So there must have been something else in the view which is triggering the setter call and passing the wrong value to it.

Comment: I agree - and upvoted your answer - my point was that he's permitting this field to be set to anything while making assumptions about what the field contains.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you should introduce types in your model fields (most notably for updateDate and creationDate).

JSF updates the model by converting any string value to the correct type specified in each field. Suppose you have a complex object, then JSF will store this in the session cache (or serialize it, depending on your faces-config.xml) and save it as a hidden attribute in the form.

When you submit the form afterwards, it will try to convert this value back to the correct type. Since the type of this field is Object, it can keep the original String representation and immediately set this field without conversion. If you restrict the type to Ranged, it will try and do the effort to convert the object, and will fail with a correct error message if this does not work.

Comment: JSF/EL does not implicitly do that. It will only do that when you *explicitly* reference the nested property in the view like `value="#{listModel.creationDate}"` in OP's case. JSF will only store the **parent** managed bean in the "session cache" (as you say it) when it's view or session scoped.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue. And i found a solution by adding the lazy atribute for dataTable like this.

```
 <p:dataTable lazy="true" var="itemOrder" value="#{orderBean.orderList}">
```

But i dont understand why.