# How do I get my JSF page to tell that a data object is not a String?

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF file that looks something like this:

```
    <ui:repeat value="child.compoundQuestion.questions" var="question">
        <h:outputText value="#{question.display}"/>
    </ui:repeat>
```

`child.compoundQuestion.questions` returns a list of objects of type `Question`, which is a simple wrapper POJO.

Unfortunately, I'm seeing this in the console:

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/employer/file.xhtml @66,58 value="#{question.display}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'display'.`

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328577/richcalendar-and-the-class-java-lang-string-does-not-have-the-property), but the `questions` setter is never called.  Based on the fact that other objects behave the way I expect elsewhere in the code (this is a pretty mature application), [I'm pretty sure I have the correct tag library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973529/cforeach-treats-items-property-as-a-string)  What else could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value="child.compoundQuestion.questions"`

Look closely. You are missing `#{}`. That's why `child.compoundQuestion.questions` is just being interpreted as a String.

I bet that not only your setter was never called, but neither was your getter =D

Comment: YOU'VE GOT TO BE FREAKING KIDDING.  Thank you, so much.  Now if you'll excuse me, I have to go create a forehead-shaped divot in my desk.